# Print %/% in sprintf along with a variable in R programming

Tags: r, printf

I tired to print the text `%/%` in `sprintf` along with a variable but I'm getting an run time error, could you please assist me how to escape and print the above said string in **R program**.

Sample code:

```
x = 5
y = 3

sprintf("The value of (x %/% y) is %d", (x %/% y))
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Error in sprintf("The value of (x %/% y) is %d", (x%/%y)) :
  invalid format '%/% y) i'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
Execution halted
```

Expected output is

```
The value of (x %/% y) is 1
```

Comment: `sprintf("The value of (x %%/%% y) is %d", (x %/% y))`. As `?sprintf` says, the function is just a wrapper around the C function `printf`, hence the dupe.

Comment: @Gregor - Thanks for the answer and I'm new in R programming.